# How to create a three-way table from two two-way tables in r

Tags: r

I have two two-way tables

```
male = as.table(matrix(c(60, 100, 20, 50), ncol=2))
colnames(male) = c("success", "failure")
rownames(male) = c("treat1", "treat2")

female = as.table(matrix(c(40, 10, 80, 30), ncol=2))
colnames(female) = c("success", "failure")
rownames(female) = c("treat1", "treat2")
```

How can I create a three-way table, named "threeway", so I can call "male" using

```
threeway[,,1]
```

and calling female using

```
threeway[,,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out a way to do this, using only the basic commands:

```
output = array(as.vector(c(male, female)), dim=c(2,2,2))
dimnames(output) = list(Treatment=c("A", "B"), 
Outcome=c("success", "failure"), Gender=c("male", "female"))

, , Gender = male

         Outcome
Treatment success failure
        A      60      20
        B     100      50

, , Gender = female

         Outcome
Treatment success failure
        A      40      80
        B      10      30
```

Answer (score 4):

like this with `abind`:

```
require(abind)
a<-abind(male,female,rev.along=0,make.names=T)

> a[,,1]
       success failure
treat1      60      20
treat2     100      50
> a[,,2]
       success failure
treat1      40      80
treat2      10      30
```